# Как сверстать белый крест

Tags: css3, html5, вёрстка

[image: ml]

Подскажите пожалуйста как сверстать белый крест

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вариантов куча... 

Один из, поставить 4 блока в один большой, всем задать `display: inline-block` и отступы по всем сторонам... а вместо плюсика - поставить псевдо-элементы `:before` - `:after` от родительского блока.

```css
.mama {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative; /* у родителя должен быть любой position, хоть absolute. 
  За счет этого все сдвиги left-bottom его внутренних элементов будут происходить
  относительно него. */
  background-color: #049;
  color: white;
  padding: 25px;
}
.big {font-size: 35px;}
.mama div {
  display: inline-block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Verdana'; 
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px;
}
.mama:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: calc(100% - 80px); /* с обеих сторон по 25 + 15px padding, x2 = 80px */
  height: 1px;
  background-color: #aaa;
  left: 40px;
  bottom: 50%;
}
.mama:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px; height: calc(100% - 80px);
  background-color: #aaa;
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="mama">
  <div><span class="big">1000+</span><br>Управление<br>продажами<br>в девелопменте</div>
  <div><span class="big">90%</span><br>Управление<br>продажами<br>в девелопменте</div>
  <br>
  <div><span class="big">1000+</span><br>Управление<br>продажами<br>в девелопменте</div>
  <div><span class="big">90%</span><br>Управление<br>продажами<br>в девелопменте</div>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое